# get oracle execution plan by sql_id

Tags: oracle, execution-plan

Is it possible to get an execution plan of currently running query by sql_id?

I couldn't succeed with:

```
select 
   DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR
        (sql_id=>'b3x6apqyskn7x') report
from dual;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('sql_id', child_number));`

You can find `sql_id` and `child_number` in `V$SESSION` (`sql_id` and `sql_child_number` columns).

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect

Comment: @MikhailAksenov: you can also pass `null` for the `child_numbeer`. In that case you will get the plans for all children